# Why my component do not update UI while data in AsyncStore change in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have three component (Login,Personal and ChangeInfo).At component Login I took the data from the server and saved the object and AsyncStore then moved the page to Personal. At Personal I retrieve data from AsyncStore and setState to states and display it on the screen. (This was successful.) At Personal I moved to ChangeInfo and updated my information here. The server returned the result successfully and I saved it to AsyncStore and returned to the Personal page. However, when switching back to Personal, the UI does not update the information that I just changed is still the old data (Meanwhile the data on the server has changed and so in AsynStore). So how do I solve this problem now?

This is code contructor() in Personal Component

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        username: "",
        fullname: "",
    }
}
```

This is code get data from AsyncStore in Personal Component

```
 componentDidMount(){
     AsyncStorage.getItem('User')
            .then((valuestr) => JSON.parse(valuestr))
            .then((data) => {
            this.setState({
                "username":data.data.UserName,
                "fullname":data.data.CustName        
            });
            });
}
```

This is code update info in ChangInfo Component

```
     _onPress() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    var data = {
        "UserName": this.state.username,
        "Password": this.state.password,
        "CustName": this.state.fullname,
        "Address": this.state.address,
        "Phone": this.state.numberphone,
        "Email": this.state.email,
        "Birthday": this.state.birthday

    }

    try {
        fetch(
          "http://readbook.vietesoft.com/api/account/Edit?clientKey=676e8b1b13e894b7bc65c085d120fc25&token=" + this.state.token,
          {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
          }
        )
          .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(function(resdata) {
            console.log("ChangeInfo" + resdata);
            if (resdata.status === true) {
              try {
                 AsyncStorage.setItem("User", JSON.stringify(resdata));
                navigate("ScreenPersonal");
                  AsyncStorage.getItem('User')
                      .then((valuestr) => JSON.parse(valuestr))
                      .then((data) => {
                          console.log("Change Info - " + data.data.UserName);
                      });


              } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
              }


            } else {

            }
          });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }


}
```

console.log("Change Info - " + data.data.UserName) have new data successfull

Comment: Hey! How do you navigate to the Personal page? Do you use the "back"-Functionality of a navigator to go back to the Personal page? If so, the UI is never updated.